# How to set visibility for ProgressBar in android MvvmCross Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am trying to set `visibility` for `ProgressBar` as `GONE`.

---

**In XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProgressBar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    local:MvxBind="Visibility Visibility(ProgressVisibility)"
    android:background="@drawable/sel_custom_progress" />
```

**In** **ViewModel**

```
private bool _progressVisibility;
public bool ProgressVisibility
{
    get { return _progressVisibility; }
    set { _progressVisibility = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => ProgressVisibility); }
}
```

---

I am setting `ProgressVisibility = false;`

---

**What is happening**: The view is still visible and not getting hidden. How to resolve this.

Comment: Which version of mvvmcross are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom value converter for `Visibility` or you can use [Visibility plugin](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/2041730778024e100c3ee6f21d79688a1f5b4d6a/MvvmCross-Plugins/Visibility)

```
public class MyVisibilityValueConverter : MvxBaseVisibilityValueConverter<bool>
{
    protected override MvxVisibility Convert(string value, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (value ==true) ? MvxVisibility.Visible : MvxVisibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

xml:

```
local:MvxBind="Visibility ProgressVisibility,Converter=MyVisibility
```

More info [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/mvvmcross-docs/blob/master/docs/_documentation/fundamentals/value-converters.md)