# mvvmcross mvxlistview property changes not reflecting in the UI

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, mvxlistview

I am using MVVMCross and InfiniteScroll IncrementalListView, I have a store view, store view model, store item view and store item view model.

The problem is in the list view I display a list of audio files. Each list item contains audio name , description, play button,download button, and progress bar.

When user clicks on play button I will make IsBusy property in Store item view model to true which is binded to progress bar visibility which works well. But after media player started playing I will make IsBusy to false but the progress bar still showing. The happens with the PlayIcon property also. I am not sure what is causing this. Please help me below is my code.

My main view model

```
using Japam.Core.ClientModels;
using Japam.Core.Services.DataServices;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Japam.Core.Helpers;
using Sequence.Plugins.InfiniteScroll;
using MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels;
using MvvmCross.Platform;
using Japam.Core.Services.PlatformServices;

namespace Japam.Core.ViewModels
{
    public class MantraStoreViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private readonly IFirebaseService fbs;
        private readonly IIncrementalCollectionFactory _incrementalCollectionFactory;
        private readonly IMantraService ms;
        private int CurrentPage = 1;
        private string startKey = "m01";
        private bool AnythingLeft = true;
        public MantraStoreViewModel(IFirebaseService firebaseService,IMantraService mantraService, IIncrementalCollectionFactory incrementalCollectionFactory)
        {
            fbs = firebaseService;
            ms = mantraService;
            _incrementalCollectionFactory = incrementalCollectionFactory;
        }
        private ObservableCollection<MantraStoreItemViewModel> _RemoteMantraas;
        public ObservableCollection<MantraStoreItemViewModel> RemoteMantraas
        {
            get { return _RemoteMantraas; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _RemoteMantraas, value); }
        }
       public void UpdateList(MantraStoreItemViewModel CurrentMantra)
        {
            int location = RemoteMantraas.IndexOf(CurrentMantra);
            RemoteMantraas.Remove(CurrentMantra);
            RemoteMantraas.Insert(location, CurrentMantra);
        }
        public void Init()
        {
            RemoteMantraas = _incrementalCollectionFactory.GetCollection<MantraStoreItemViewModel>(async (count, pageSize) => {
                ObservableCollection<MantraStoreItemViewModel> newMantraas = new ObservableCollection<MantraStoreItemViewModel>();
                    if (AnythingLeft)
                    {
                        var mantraas = await fbs.GetMantraas(startKey, CurrentPage);
                        if (mantraas != null)
                        {
                            if (mantraas.Count < Settings.StorePageSize)
                                AnythingLeft = false;
                            foreach (var mantra in mantraas)
                            {
                               newMantraas.Add(new MantraStoreItemViewModel(Mvx.GetSingleton<ISimplePlayService>()) { MantraItem = mantra.Object } );
                            }
                        startKey = "m" + (mantraas.Count + 1);
                        } 
                    }
                return newMantraas;
            },Settings.StorePageSize);
        }

    }
}
```

My main view axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <include android:id="@+id/toolbar" layout="@layout/toolbar" />
  <Sequence.Plugins.InfiniteScroll.Droid.IncrementalListView
        android:smoothScrollbar="true"
        android:scrollingCache="false"
        android:animationCache="false"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:divider="@color/primary"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource RemoteMantraas;"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/mantrastoreitem" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My store Item view model

```
using Japam.Core.ClientModels;
using MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels;
using Japam.Core.Services.PlatformServices;
using Japam.Core.Common;

namespace Japam.Core.ViewModels
{
    public class MantraStoreItemViewModel: MvxViewModel
    {

        private Mantra _MantraItem;
        private ISimplePlayService playService;
        public MantraStoreItemViewModel(ISimplePlayService _playService)
        {
            playService = _playService;
            playService.MediaEnded = MediaEnded;
            playService.MediaBusyChanged = MediaBusyChanged;
            PlayIcon = AppConstants.Icons.FAIcons[AppConstants.FAIconNames.FAPlayCircleO];
        }
        public void MediaEnded()
        {
            PlayIcon = AppConstants.Icons.FAIcons[AppConstants.FAIconNames.FAPlayCircleO];
        }
        public void MediaBusyChanged(bool status)
        {
            IsBusy = status;//not working here
        }
        private bool _IsBusy;
        public bool IsBusy
        {
            get { return _IsBusy; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _IsBusy, value); }
        }
        public Mantra MantraItem
        {
            get { return _MantraItem; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _MantraItem, value); }
        }
        private FontAwesomeIcon _PlayIcon;
        public FontAwesomeIcon PlayIcon
        {
            get { return _PlayIcon; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _PlayIcon, value); }
        }
        private MvxCommand _DownloadCommand;
        public MvxCommand DownloadCommand
        {
            get
            {
                _DownloadCommand = _DownloadCommand ?? new MvxCommand(() => Download());
                return _DownloadCommand;
            }
        }
        private void Download()
        {

        }

        private MvxCommand _PlayCommand;
        public MvxCommand PlayCommand
        {
            get
            {
                _PlayCommand = _PlayCommand ?? new MvxCommand(() => Play());
                return _PlayCommand;
            }
        }
        private void Play()
        {
            PlayIcon = AppConstants.Icons.FAIcons[AppConstants.FAIconNames.FAStopCircleO];
            IsBusy = true;//works here
            playService.Play(MantraItem.AudioFileName);
        }

    }
}
```

My store item axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:id="@+id/txtMantraName"
             android:gravity="center_vertical"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
             android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
             android:foreground="@color/primarytext"
             android:textSize="20dp"
             local:MvxBind="Text MantraItem.MantraName" />
  <TextView   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/txtMantraFor"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"
              android:textSize="15dp"
              android:layout_below="@id/txtMantraName"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
              android:foreground="@color/secondartext"
              local:MvxBind="Text MantraItem.MantraFor" />
  <Plugin.Iconize.Droid.Controls.IconButton
       android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
       android:textSize="15dp"
       android:textColor="@color/accent"
       android:layout_gravity="right"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
       local:MvxBind="Text PlayIcon,Converter=FontAwesomeToText;Click PlayCommand" />
  <Plugin.Iconize.Droid.Controls.IconButton
     android:id="@+id/btnDownload"
     android:textSize="15dp"
     android:textColor="@color/accent"
     android:text="{fa-download}"
     android:layout_gravity="right"
     android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_below="@id/btnPlay"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
     local:MvxBind="Click DownloadCommand" />

  <ProgressBar
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/ctrlActivityIndicator"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
   android:indeterminateOnly="true"
   android:keepScreenOn="true"
   local:MvxBind="Visibility IsBusy,Converter=VisibleOrInvisible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: someone please help me

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `local:MvxBind="Visibility Visibility(IsBusy)"`  See here: https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/value-converters?#the-mvx-visibility-valueconverters

Comment: I have the converter it works first time but not after media player completion @pnavk

Comment: Perhaps this can help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44224694/how-to-set-visibility-for-progressbar-in-android-mvvmcross-xamarin

Comment: The answer there says to create a value converter which I have done

Comment: Then I would recommend using this: https://github.com/MvvmCross/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/blob/master/N-34-Progress/Waiting/Waiting.Droid/Views/BindableProgress.cs. I have used this in my MvvmCross android app and know it works. Here is the post from Stuart that covers this: http://slodge.blogspot.com/2013/07/n34-showing-progress-isbusy-display-n1.html

Comment: Okay will try that Thank you